# TestCategory on class level instead test methods

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mstest

I want to categorize unit tests but I don't want to put TestCategory attribute at each test method and instead I want to do it on class level. I know Nunit does it, but MS test doesn't. Any idea? I want to run categorized test in Jenkins after the fact

Comment: Depends on what you mean with categorize? In VS (at least in 2013 premium version) you can Group on: Class, Duration, Outcome, Traits (== TestCategory) and Projet.

Answer (score 2):

You're right, MSTest doesn't allow you to do that. An alternative is to split your tests into separate test assemblies for organizational purposes. I usually do that with broad categories (e.g. MyAssembly.Tests.Unit and MyAssembly.Tests.Integration, for differentiating between unit and integration tests).

Or, of course, you could change test frameworks. MStest and NUnit are similar enough that changing frameworks is mostly a search-and-replace operation.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to Daniel Mann's answer. You can also make two different TestClass withing same CS file or same project. This will help to avoid taking care of two test assemblies as well as give flexibility to  to open a single sln project to work on all test methods.

```
[TestClass]
public class Unitests
{

}

[TestClass]
public class IntegrationTests
{

}
```